# why google analytic show unknown (not set) location?

Tags: google-analytics, geolocation, ip, alexa-internet

I saw in Google analytic there are big number of visits are from unknown (not set).
also in Alexa around 34% visits location is unknown.

Comment: Do you have the particular IP address with empty location? We need to have the particular IP address to provide answer.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/03/19/locations-report-google-analytics/

> As in any field in Google Analytics, (not set) means the information wasn’t captured for some reason. In this instance, GA could not determine where someone was located from their IP address.
>
> You might check what browser they where using.  It may be due to usage of Opera Mini as the browser, which actually fetches web pages to an Opera server and then sends a compressed version on to the mobile device (in which case your website never has a direct connection with the device to determine its IP address).

Comment: When lifting text off another website you should attribute or reference the source, the text above is exactly the same as on http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/03/19/locations-report-google-analytics/ which appears to pre-date this answer.

Comment: Feel free to edit it, this is from back when I first joined I was probably worried about link only anwsers.